# PostGIS - Finding aggregated counts on dissolved polygons

Tags: count, union, postgis, with-statement

I have set this WITH query to get dissolved polygons where polygons overlap:

`CREATE TABLE public.dissolve_intrsct AS 
        ( WITH dissolved AS(
          SELECT ST_Union(pt.geom) as geom, count(geom) as buff_ct,
           count(pt.count) as intrsct_ct
           FROM public.intrsct_buff as pt
         )

           SELECT (ST_DUMP(geom)).geom::geometry(POLYGON, 2263), intrsct_ct, buff_ct
            FROM dissolved);`

My output returns the geometry(good), but also returns the total count of all geometries before the query(59144) for both `intrsct_buff` and `buff_ct`

[image]

I want the query to return the number of polygons that were dissolved to create the new polygon. (i.e. If three polygons overlap, after this query I want `buff_ct` to return **3**, along with intrsct_ct just returning the original count I had in `public.intrsct_buff`)

Answer (score 0):

I found what needed to be done..

After creating this table and adding a PRIMARY KEY `ID`, I then used `ST_Intersects` to find where my dissolved polygons intersected with the original buffer, and counted the number of intersecting polygons.
See code below:
`

```
CREATE TABLE dissolve_ct AS(
SELECT ds.id, ds.geom, count(pt.geom) AS
buff_ct
FROM public.dissolve_intrsct as ds 
LEFT JOIN public.intrsct_buff as pt
ON ST_Intersects(ds.geom, pt.geom)
GROUP BY ds.id
    );
```

`